# Possible to combine matching UV's after seaming together mesh?

Tags: mesh, uv

I recently was correcting a meshy mistake, and I basically cropped out a section of a torso on a model and replaced it with the original torso, and then merged the mesh vertices back together. The UV's were named differently, despite being the same
uv layout/material/texture. Is there a way to combine the UV's back into a single UV, or do I need to start completely over?It's showing both UV's in the list and applying them based on which UV i select.

[image: Image shows the combined mesh but the split UV]

Comment: copy/paste, maybe.From the UV menu, as there is no shortcut, I think.

Comment: You could use GN to rebuild a new UV and then convert the attribute, if needed, to turn it back into "native" UV.  You could use two data transfer modifiers, to rebuild a frankenstein UV from two different maps onto a single map.  Both of these are probably more tedious than you're looking for.  Or, you could just roll back to before joining, name the UV maps to the same thing, and join then.